# Where would I find the css bootstrap after installing it via the composer?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I am new to composer.
I am trying to add [CSS booststrap](http://getbootstrap.com) tp my laravel 5.1 project

To download the framework This is the command that I used

```
composer require twbs/bootstrap
```

But I can't find the css files in my laravel project.

Is there another step that I will need to make the CSS booststrap part of my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this has changed since Laravel 5.0, but bootstrap is included by default in the default `app.blade.php` view.

That may help you, but if you want the css files to also be local, check in the `/vendor` directory or `public/css` one.

Comment: I will need to include the bootstrap.min.css file into my project.I do not see ant booststrap in the vender folder. Also, I do not css CSS folder in my public folder. there is a folder call "boostrap" next to the "app" folder but I do not see any css file in there. Not sure how to include it.

Comment: If your using the minified file, you probably aren't editing it.  I'd suggest using a CDN and include it at the top of your view files (or parent view file if you use a parent).  In other words something like  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">` in your view files.  I wouldn't bother downloading it as CDNs have caching benefits that serving it yourself will not have.

Comment: I rather not use CDN rather have it local

Comment: I wouldn't use composer to do such a simple task then.  Just download the minified CSS file and put it in the `public/css`.  Then include that in your view file.  Similar process.  Installing via composer is more than likely pulling in the LESS files somewhere.